# How to give alias name to commands in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, alias, ipython-magic

I want to give an alias to a command in jupyter notebook such that if i write:

```
Get me list of all students
```

[image: If i write this in jupyter cell]
this alias name will call a command that I have written and show the desired result

[image]

Please help.

Comment: These had better not be real data

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may contain personal data

Answer (score 1):

IPython is the Python backend to the Jupyter Notebook, which is also known as the kernel, if you want to add an alias to Jupiter you can add an alias to IPython since all commands are executed there:

For more information check this website: [IPython Alias to Preload Your Favorite Modules and Activate Autoreload](https://towardsdatascience.com/tips-ipython-d5ea85c5e9be)

Also, IPython reads a configuration file in start-up, by editing this file you can define an alias, check this website for more information: [Customization configuration file](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Edock/manuals/IPython/node7.html)

If the file doesn't exist create one: [Introduction to IPython configuration](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/intro.html)

Comment: How to make it callable like instead of autoreload  I want to call it whenever I want.

Comment: Try adding  ->    alias alias_name command_string    to your ipythonrc file  @AnujAggarwal

Comment: For example: alias ipy="ipython --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="['Your python code']""

Comment: Suppose 'get all students data' is alias name I want to give, how can I put it in that command.

Comment: I am new to Jupyter Notebook . Can you tell me the location of this rc file which I need to edit?

Comment: Try: alias get all students data = "ipython --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="['Your python code']"" I would suggest you change the alias name for a single word command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217451/discussion-between-anuj-aggarwal-and-mateo-lara).